# Windows batch file not outputting variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file to create weekly backups.  I create a variable called mydate which I use to both format the output folder and to echo for the log.  When I run the batch with each line redirected to the log file, it works fine:

```
set mydate=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%
echo My Date is %mydate% >>TestEchoLog.txt
echo Backup triggered at %mydate% >>TestEchoLog.txt
```

Cmd window:

```
D:\>set mydate=2017-06-26
D:\>echo My Date is 2017-06-26  1>>TestEchoLog.txt
D:\>echo Backup triggered at 2017-06-26   1>>TestEchoLog.txt
```

TestEchoLog.txt:

```
My Date is 2017-06-26 
Backup triggered at 2017-06-26
```

However, if I wrap the commands into a single redirect, my variables stop working:

```
>>TestEchoLog.txt (
set mydate=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%
echo My Date is %mydate% 
echo Backup triggered at %mydate%
```

Cmd window:

```
D:\>(
set mydate=2017-06-26
 echo My Date is
 echo Backup triggered at
) 1>>TestEchoLog.txt
```

TestEchoLog.txt:

```
My Date is  
Backup triggered at
```

How can I fix this?  Obviously a workaround is to just have the redirect on every line, but it's a long enough instruction set that I'd rather not.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your variable before echoing it into the file :

```
set mydate=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%
(
echo My Date is %mydate% 
echo Backup triggered at %mydate%
)>>TestEchoLog.txt
```